# Check if string is palindrome at "i" letters?

Tags: haskell, string-length

I got a program that checks if string is palindrome or not. I want to add functionality that lets user check if given string is palindrome at i letters. For example if string is "abbaabba" and user gives number 4 it returns true because "abba" is palindrome. If user gives 5 then it returns false, because "abbaa" is not palindrome.

This is what I've done so far

```
palindromes:: String -> Int -> Bool

palindromes p i
   | p == reverse p = True
   | otherwise = False
```

How do I add that functionality?

Comment: You first let it *take* `i` letters from the string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `take i(p) == take i(reverse p) = True` ? It returns false on some occasions when it should return true.

Comment: You did it the wrong way for the right operand: it should be `reverse (take i p)`

Comment: You don't even  use `i` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**`take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) here to pre-process the string:

```
palindromes :: Eq a => [a] -> Int -> Bool
palindromes p i = p' == reverse p'
    where p' = take i p
```